# How can I get PHP redirect to work in a frame?

Tags: javascript, php, html, frames

I have a page that uses two frames, the top frame displays a username and the bottom frame displays that user's website. However, before the bottom frame displays the website it does some backend database work.

Relevant code of main html (note: variables passed change with each refresh):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="30">
</head>
<frameset rows="20%, 80%">
<frame src="search-results.php?user=<?php echo $row['user'];?>" name="content1">
<frame src="a3track.php?user=<?php echo $row['user'];?>&url=<?php echo $row['url'];?>" name="content2">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Relevant code of top frame page (search-results.php):

```
<?php
$user=$_GET['user'];
echo '<html><head></head><body>' . $user . '</body></html>';
?>
```

Relevant code of bottom frame page (a3track.php):

```
<?php
$user=$_GET['user'];
$url=$_GET['url'];
// do some database work here
//Then redirect to client's website
$redirect_to = "http://" . $url;
echo '<script>
<!--
window.location = "'.$redirect_to.'"
-->
</script>';
?>
```

What should happen is that the client's website appears in the bottom frame for 30 seconds but after doing the database work the frame remains blank.

If I run the page a3track.php by itself in a stand-alone window it works, displaying the redirected website correctly after doing the database work, but it does not do that when inside the frame.

I am guessing that something needs to be changed in the script part of a3track.php but I don't know what and cannot find any clues in the loads of sites and pages i have perused in search of an answer.

Comment: Have you had a look at your server's error log?

Comment: About `<frameset>` - From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset *"**Deprecated** This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."*

Comment: The problem almost certainly has nothing to do with the redirect and everything to do with the frame. The client probably has [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) set to forbid framing.

Comment: *Warning:* Your code is vulnerable to XSS. Specifically, a crafted URL such as `?url="+location.host+location.pathname+"#";eval("evil stuff here");//` will allow malicious code to run in your website.

Comment: This is not a public page. it is inside a passworded area, and the frame function works perfectly in the same browser using another site written in VBScript for ASP uisng the response.redirect function

Comment: @NicoHaase the logs do not show any errors and the page is set to show errors in the browser as it  does not have public access.

Comment: You were talking about 30 seconds of time till the lower frame goes blank - could this be connected to the `max_execution_time` of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to debug features which are deprecated (for quite some time). Using frames is not a good idea anymore, it can work, but you can be pretty sure that it won't work anymore soon and each browser can handle it quite differntly.
If you want to stick with your plan you could try a php-redirect

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com');
```

But I cannot guarantee that this will work, it's just a guess.

I'd recommend to switch everything to a modern system. You can build a page which has an iframe in which you can load the clients-website. So you can do all the database-stuff on the page itself and when it's done the page gets shown with the iframe loaded which directs to the clients-website. I'm pretty sure this'd remove some of the problems you have.

Comment: Hello. Now that I realise frameset has been deprecated I have decided to find another way to rewrite everything. Thank you all for your comments :-)